# No specs found Reshaper(2017.2.2) TypeScript(2.6.1) Jasmine(2.7.0) when using import {}

Tags: typescript, jasmine, resharper

Setup:

- Visual Studio 2017
- Reshaper(2017.2.2)
- TypeScript(2.6.1)
- Jasmine(2.7.0)

Problem:

- The browser show the web test launcher with the message "No specs found"
- Console error visible: Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined at referenceFile:2
- Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined at Tests.js:2

Other information:

From the developement tool if i click on referenceFile:2 I can see the source JS code of the file, with this content:

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var User = (function () {
    function User(name, surname) {
        this._name = name;
        this._surname = surname;
    }
    Object.defineProperty(User.prototype, "Name", {
        get: function () {
            return this._name;
        },
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true
    });
    Object.defineProperty(User.prototype, "Surname", {
        get: function () {
            return this._surname;
        },
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true
    });
    return User;
}());
exports.User = User;
//# sourceMappingURL=User.js.map
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es5"],
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "nodejs-console-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "NodejsConsoleApp",
  "main": "app.js",
  "author": {
    "name": "ms"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^6.0.87",
    "jasmine": "^2.8.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.2"
  }
}
```

Any idea on how I can solve the problem?

UPDATE: 
The problem is caused by the commonJs module type specified in tsconfig.json.
This is the default value proposed by many templates and is the one I use the most.
CommonJS unfortunately cannot be executed in the browser straight away, it needs to be packed/browserified in order to be executable in a browser.
For the source code I use Gulp>browserify and everything works correctly.

My expectation would be to have resharper doing the dirty job for me, but it is not.
How can I use resharper to run those tests with no error, in my case I wouldn't even need the browser to open so it could run in node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TypeScript module compilation does matter, I was using CommonJS but this is not supported by browsers and R# is not doing anything about it.

In tsconfig.json > compilerOptions > module, you can specify one of the following option: commonjs, amd, system, umd, es6.

With R# you can and should use **es6**

For more information about this:
[Typescript Modules](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html)
[Typescript Module Resolution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html)